# IntelliJ gets stuck on "Copying resources"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Had a problem trying to debug a Java application that I had using IntelliJ IDEA 13.

When attempting debugging, it would get stuck in the make process, displaying "Copying resources" indefinitely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, it got stuck because I had manually created two named pipes in the same folder. Deleting the pipes allowed the make process to terminate successfully.

EDIT: I'm only posting this because Googling did not give me any good results, and I think it would save someone else some time if they could find it easily when it occurs.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem. I think its because i had setup angular project for UI inside my webapp folder, because of this it was loading all the dependencies from node_modules folder which takes lot of time.

When i took backup of my that angular project and deleted it from the webapp, it worked.